# Flutter - Map JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to DART / FLUTER and still have a lot of difficulties. I have a registration function and I need to return 2 attributes that are within a Json MAP. Constructs the function below but returns error

> [ERROR: flutter / lib / ui / ui_dart_state.cc (157)] Unhandled Exception: type _InternalLinkedHashMap ' is not a subtype of type List

Can you help me?

About my code:

```
    saveClient(Cliente cliente) async {
      final Map<String, dynamic> clienteMap = {
        "nome": cliente.nome,
        "email": cliente.email,
        "senha": cliente.senha,
        "celular": cliente.celular,
      };

      final String clientJson = jsonEncode(clienteMap);
      client.post(baseUrl + '/usuario',
          headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'password': 'admin'},
          body: clientJson);


      final Response response = await client.get(baseUrl + '/usuario/id');
      final List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final List<ClienteDto> dataUser = List();
      for (Map<String, dynamic> clienteJson in decodedJson) {
        final ClienteDto cliente = ClienteDto(
          clienteJson['id'],
          clienteJson['nome'],
        );
        dataUser.add(cliente);
        print(dataUser);
      }
      return dataUser;
    }
```

Comment: At which line are you getting this error? It's hard to give an answer without more details.

Comment: This line: final List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign your decoded JSON response, which is `Map`, to a `List` which isn't a valid assignment. You should try printing the result of `jsonDecode(response.body)` to figure out where the actual portion of the result you care about is within the response.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I'm new to the Dart language, I started using it only 2 weeks ago. The print that is in the code just put it for testing purposes. What I really need is for the values ​​of [id] and [nome] sent as registration data to be assigned to a variable. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Not a problem, I'm happy to help. Can you share the output of `jsonDecode(response.body)`?

Comment: Just a heads up @Hudson_Nunes - you didn't update your post, you added an update as an answer to your question. You should take the additional content and add it to your question instead since it's not a valid answer to your question.

Comment: +1 to BJHStudios comment. Also, it appears that you're not issuing a valid request so your response body contains an error.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I go remake my question on another post.

Answer (score -1):

This is my all code of class WebClient:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http_interceptor/http_interceptor.dart';
import 'package:owlwee/Models/Cartao.dart';
import 'package:owlwee/Models/Cliente.dart';
import 'package:owlwee/Models/ClienteDto.dart';

final Client client =
    HttpClientWithInterceptor.build(interceptors: [LoggingInterceptor()]);

const String baseUrl = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8080'; // LEROMA
const String baseUrlCheckIn = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:8081'; // LEROMA


class LoggingInterceptor implements InterceptorContract {
  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({RequestData data}) async {
    print('Request');
    print('Headers: ${data.headers}');
    print('body: ${data.body}');
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
    print('Status ${data.statusCode}');
    print('Headers: ${data.headers}');
    print('body: ${data.body}');
    return data;
  }
}

saveClient(Cliente cliente) async {
  final Map<String, dynamic> clienteMap = {
    "nome": cliente.nome,
    "email": cliente.email,
    "senha": cliente.senha,
    "celular": cliente.celular,
  };

  final String clientJson = jsonEncode(clienteMap);
  client.post(baseUrl + '/usuario',
      headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'password': 'admin'},
      body: clientJson);


  final Response response = await client.get(baseUrl + '/usuario/id');
  final List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
  final List<ClienteDto> dataUser = List();
  for (Map<String, dynamic> clienteJson in decodedJson) {
    final ClienteDto cliente = ClienteDto(
      clienteJson['id'],
      clienteJson['nome'],
    );
    dataUser.add(cliente);
    print(dataUser);
  }
  return dataUser;
}
```

And this is answer of console:

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/flutter (15631): Request
I/flutter (15631): Headers: {Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8, password: admin}
I/flutter (15631): body: {"nome":"Hudson","email":"hudson@email.com","senha":"123456","celular":21987987987}
I/flutter (15631): Request
I/flutter (15631): Headers: {}
I/flutter (15631): body: 
I/flutter (15631): Status 400
I/flutter (15631): Headers: {connection: close, content-type: application/json, date: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 00:38:37 GMT, transfer-encoding: chunked}
I/flutter (15631): body: {"timestamp":"2020-02-05T00:38:37.040+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"id\"","trace":"org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"id\"\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:133)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(Invocable
E/flutter (15631): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
E/flutter (15631): #0      saveClient (package:owlwee/http/webclient.dart:83:23)
E/flutter (15631): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15631): #1      _CadastroState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:owlwee/Views/Cadastro.dart:192:25)
E/flutter (15631): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (15631): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (15631): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (15631): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (15631): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (15631): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
E/flutter (15631): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (15631): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
E/flutter (15631): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (15631): #11     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (15631): #12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (15631): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (15631): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (15631): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (15631): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (15631): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (15631): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (15631): 
I/flutter (15631): Status 201
I/flutter (15631): Headers: {content-type: application/json, location: http://192.168.1.9:8080/usuario/9, date: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 00:38:37 GMT, transfer-encoding: chunked}
I/flutter (15631): body: {"id":9,"nome":"Hudson"}
```

Is that what you asked?